# state in useSelector is not covered in unit test

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, mocking

I have below code snippet:

```
const appInstances = useSelector(
        useCallback(
            (state) =>
                state.instances.filter(
                    x =>
                        x.parentInstanceId === instanceId),
            [instanceId]
        )
    );
```

I have the mock function to mock the return value for useSelector

```
 const useSelectorSpy = jest.spyOn(redux, 'useSelector');
        useSelectorSpy.mockReturnValue(appInstances);
```

However, in code coverage report it shows below parts are not covered:

```
(state) =>
                state.instances.filter(
                    x =>
                        x.parentInstanceId === instanceId),
```

How we can cover the missing part in test cases? Thanks

Comment: How did you use `appInstances` state slice? Please provide minimal, complete code

Comment: You should not memoize `useSelector` with `useCallback`, there's no need for this. Also, selectors are pure functions so you can test them in isolation without any spies or mocks.